# Multisampling of an ADC channel in a PWM cycle in TI C2000

Tags: sampling, analog-to-digital

I want to sample an ADC channel multiple times in one PWM cycle.

I can trig any ADC channel in anywhere in my PWM timer counter now. But I want to trig and sample same channel in many times within a pwm period.

I tried to explain by drawing below.
[image: lt]

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Have you tried the TI forums? That's the best place

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your PWM above is ePWM1.

1. Configure ePWM4 to be synchronized to ePWM1.
2. Adjust ePWM4 period to be N times smaller.
3. Now configure the ADC sampling to ePWM4. Assuming you sample on the bottom and top of ePWM4 triangle, you will sample twice per ePWM4 period and 2*N times per ePWM1 period.

Since ePWM1 and ePWM4 are frequency-locked and phased-locked, it will be as if you sample at specific instants on the ePWM1 triangle.

In the image below I adjusted ePWM4 frequency to be 4 times greater than ePWM1. Thus, I would sample 8 times per ePWM1 period. You could also adjust the starting phase of ePWM4 to further adjust the sampling instants.

[image]